# Anchor tags not working in absolute positioned div

Tags: css, wordpress

I have placed a  tag  with social media icons absolutely within a container div on a Wordpress site and doing so has broken my anchor tags. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

If you inspect the element of the social media icons near the top of the page you can see there are anchor tags there, but you can't click on them. I don't see anything that they are inheriting that would be causing this either. Here is the link to the site: http://finesconehengebakingco.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apply this css to each anchor tag:

```
<a style="position:relative; z-index:10;">
```

I think it is because the anchor tag is behind the image so you can't click it, this will put it on top.

Hope this helps.

Comment: no problem, if this helped you press the green tick please ;)